# Bootstrap fixed column size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like the right side of the column to be set to a fixed size of 400px wide while the left hand portion is 100% of the difference.

Current code:

```
<div class="container-fluid fill">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="leftpanel" class="col-md-8">
    </div>
    <div id="rightpanel" class="col-md-4">
    </div>
</div>
```

How would I go about doing this with Bootstrap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not only with bootstrap but even with nay CSS trick it is something tough to set a column fixed width in Pixels and rest one is 100% of the rest portion of screen because each device have different resolution. Still if you want to achieve this than you should look at the calc() function of css. Though it is not supported by all modern browser but would be helpful to you.